# Ontapi Runtime Error including openllet 2.6.3

Tags: owl-api, pellet

Adding opellet 2.6.3 to Maven project including Ontapi throws the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TSV
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntFormat.<clinit>(OntFormat.java:61)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.guessFormat(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:752)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.getSupportedFormats(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:774)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.read(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:795)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.readGraph(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:725)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.loadGraph(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:580)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl$ONTLoaderImpl.load(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:286)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:109)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OntologyFactoryImpl.java:58)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManagerImpl.load(OntologyManagerImpl.java:1678)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManagerImpl.load(OntologyManagerImpl.java:1644)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OntologyManagerImpl.java:1587)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OntologyManager.java:243)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OntologyManager.java:259)
at ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OntologyManager.java:58)
```

The code tested is the following:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OntManagers.createONT();   
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLOntology ontology=manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(
        new File("ontologies/E1G1.owl"));
```

My pom file contains the following dependencies:ontapi1 .1.0, jena-arq 3.6.0,  openllet-pellint 2.6.3.

Comment: I see openllet-jena:2.6.3 uses jena 3.4.0, while ont-api:1.1.0 - jena 3.6.0. Try to fix your pom by excluding jena from openllet-jena dependency, it should help

Comment: The problem is conflicting owlapi versions not Jena versions, although both might be an issue.

Comment: OntFormat is a part of ont-api, Lang.TSV is a new jena-format which I added for generality and for the future (but maybe it was not very smart decision). That Lang is absent in jena 3.4.0. Moreover, I tested ontapi+openpellet together with jena 3.6.0 - everything seems to be worked, although it was not deep testing. Also I tested spin(based on jena-arq 3.4.0)+ontapi - i.e. sparql queries - there are no significant changes with queries and graphs in jena's 3.4 and 3.6. So increasing version seems to be safe. As for owlapi, both products uses owlapi-5.1.4, so no dependency conflicts are expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you only have one owlapi version in the claaspath. The stack trace implies there are at least two versions.

Comment: I've added my pom dependecies, and it seems there is no conflict.

Comment: The code might have been compiled against a different version than the one mentioned in the pom. It's definitely an issue with the wrong class being used at runtime.

Comment: Right, it's a issue with the wrong class. Modifying the import entry solved the problem. Many thanks.